# Executing stored procedures on SQL Azure database using REST API or Azure Management Libraries

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-sql-database

Is there a way to create an execute stored procedures on SQL Azure database using REST API or Azure Management Libraries?

I checked Operations for Azure SQL Databases here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn505719.aspx and Management Libraries for .NET here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn602775(v=azure.11).aspx, and I don't see any options.

Comment: You might want to consider utilising OData instead and remove the need for sprocs.

Comment: Maybe you could give me some links so that I could understand your idea better. Thanks.

Comment: As of what I read I see that it is possible to use OData to query the DB, retrieve information, add data. But what about system stored procedures like sp_adduser or something?

Comment: OData is an open standard - details at http://www.odata.org/. You need to expose your Database using a logic tier that can be written in whatever language you like. You can expose Stored Procedures in your logic tier easily enough.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, this is something you would need to do in your application. The REST API provides management capabilities at the infrastructure/platform level. Procedure execution would fall under application level IMHO. Management Library for .Net is simply a wrapper around these REST API.

I think your only option would be write your own API specific for your application/database that can execute the stored procedure in your database.

Comment: Thank you. I will vote your answer up when l get enough reputation.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are developing in Azure consider automatic REST API from SlashDB, which is available from their Marketplace.

https://azuremarketplace.microsoft.com/en-us/marketplace/apps/vte.slashdb

It allows for defining an API end-point in Transact-SQL to call a stored procedure by way of an HTTP GET request to a URL with parameters. In addition to that, SlashDB reflects the entire database as URL-linked graph-like structure so a lot of queries need not even be written.

Disclosure: I am the founder and CEO of the company behind SlashDB, but you don't have to take my word it - just try it.

Comment: could not find it :(

Comment: it moved https://azuremarketplace.microsoft.com/en-us/marketplace/apps/vte.slashdb